# Variable set to random number, then printed, then input, correct input (variable) prints x

Tags: python

Ok so here is what a trying to do.

1. Am creating a random number.
2. Am printing it.
3. Am prompting the user to input the number that was printed.
4. Then 'if' the number entered = the number printed (the variable) x will happen.

Ok am confused hopefully your not.

```
import random
var = random.randint(1000,9999)
print(var)
ask = input('Please enter pin. ')
if ask == var :
    print('thank you')
```

Then numbers print but when enter nothing happens.
Thank you

Comment: `input` returns a string, `1111  != '1111'` so you need to cast to an `int`

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: python 3, TMJ big thanks.

Comment: Tip: you can `print(type(ask))` to confirm it's a string

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your input is a string, which you compare to an int. This should work:

```
if int(ask) == var :
    print('thank you')
```

A different approach would be to convert the variable to an int directly (as pointed out by Alex.S and cricket_007). This is better if you later use the variable as an integer again. The first way would be better if you want to later use `ask` as a string. This would look like this:

```
ask = int(input('Please enter pin. '))
if ask == var :
    print('thank you')
```

Thanks again for cricket_007 for pointing out, that a non-numerical value will crash this code. To avoid this you can check with the `isnumeric()` function:

```
ask = input('Please enter pin. ')
if not ask.isnumeric():
    print('Invalid input')
    exit()
ask = int(ask)
```

This will exit without an error after prompting an message, if the user inputs something that isn't a number.

Comment: I think turning var into a string is a less error prone solution

Comment: I basically changed 'ask == var' to 'ask != var' now it works. Should I alter more of the code?

Comment: `ask != var` should always be true, no matter the input, as you are still comparing a string to an integer. Have you tested other input that produce both outputs (thank you and no thank you)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your input variable to a number:

`ask = int(input('Please enter pin. '))`

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine in Python 2.7. However, in Python 3 you will need to do the following:

```
if int(ask) == var:
    print('thank you')
```

Comment: I basically changed 'ask == var' to 'ask != var' now it works. Am working with 3.4

Answer (score 0):

The recommendations to convert your input to an int are fine, but only if you are going to be entering numbers into your input. Otherwise, the code will error out.

The way to prevent that is switch the variable that is casted

```
if ask == str(var) :
```

Comment: I noticed that when i entered a word, so it seems this modification would be sufficient on its own